# QMainWindow that ignore clicks, passes them on to background windows

Tags: qt

I'd like to create a semi-transparent information window that doesn't get in the way of the user's other activities. Any clicks on the window should just pass through as if the window wasn't there.

How would you recommend implementing such behavior? Is there an easy way to do it or do I have to follow a clumsy workaround? I'm thinking of hiding the window, re-executing the click, then making the window visible again. But this would still screw up drag'n'drop gestures.

Comment: Have you ever managed to implement this? I'm trying to implement the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at an enum value of [Qt::WidgetAttribute](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum): `Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents`:

> When enabled, this attribute disables the delivery of mouse events to
>   the widget and its children. Mouse events are delivered to other
>   widgets as if the widget and its children were not present in the
>   widget hierarchy; mouse clicks and other events effectively "pass
>   through" them. This attribute is disabled by default.

Comment: Like [this](http://i.imgur.com/yGB2Q.png)? I could be wrong, but it doesn't seem to work for windows.

Comment: @Pieter Would you like your clicks to pass through your semi-transparent information window to another window which belongs to the same or another application?

Comment: @Pieter What is important here is that as far as I know your clicks on the semi-transparent information window having the Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents attribute are received by another window if and only if that window belongs to the same Qt application. I checked the Qt source and the attribute mentioned affects the behaviour of `QWidget * QApplication::widgetAt ( const QPoint & point ) [static]` which is used internally to decide which window of the application gets the mouse event.

Comment: Dang... then this solution won't work for me, I guess. I need my mouse events to pass through the window no matter what's behind it.

Comment: In this case I think the Qt API alone can not help you solve this problem. You need to work with the native APIs of each OS. (I can help you with win32. You can get the window system identifier (HWND) of the widget by `WId QWidget::effectiveWinId () const`. Then you can set the `WS_EX_NOACTIVATE` [Extended Window Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) by the [SetWindowLong](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.)

Comment: I've never worked with the Windows API before and this would break the app's cross-platform compatibility, so that's definitely a non-trivial inconvenience. Thanks -- I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little more research into "mouse event transparency" (didn't know the exact terminology) and I found [this](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/35684-How-pass-part-of-the-mouse-events-through-a-top-level-window-to-the-windows-below?p=164778#post164778).

> I don't think there is a general and easy approach to your problem. You will probably have to dig into the native API. Once events reach an application they are not forwarded to other applications on their own.

What do you guys think? Am I doomed to work with the native APIs of each OS?